# Is the English phrase "I'm cool in, anyway" right?

Tags: expressions

I'm writing an English oral script for a test. In my script, there are three roommates in a dormitory.

> A asks them: 'Guys, did you got any plan for this holiday?'
>
> B replied: 'Not really, any idea? I'm cool in anyway.'

I want to express that 'B' feel good about whatever 'A' suggested; how should I express it like English native speakers? Don't pay attention to *grammar*; just do people use this expression in spoken English?

Comment: no, I have never heard anyone say, “I’m cool in”.  “I’m cool with whatever.”  would be much more idiomatic.   Also, not “did you got” just “got any plans...”  also not “this holiday”  “the holiday”

Comment: What regional dialect are you thinking of? Spoken colloquial language is very dependent on regionality: what's perfectly normal in Jamaica might be meaningless in Boston; what's said in Glasgow might not be understood in, well, *anywhere*. Where I'm from (Australia), we might say "Guys, wotch y'up to for the holidays?" "Dunno; any ideas? I'm easy."

Comment: Just a point: in your explanation 'B' is a single third person so _I want to express that 'B' feel good_ should read _I want to express that 'B' **feels** good_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brit here, so my UK take would be:

A: "Guys, have you got any plans for the holidays?"

B: "Not really. Any ideas? I'm cool with anything."

Comment: That would sound normal in Canadian English as well (which tends to be close to US).